# Keep the emoji keyboard between segues

Tags: objective-c, keyboard, ios8, segue, emoji

I'm working in this iOS project with Emojis, but since iOS 8 when you switch between segues the keyboard restarts to a QWERTY position. I need to maintain the emoji keyboard because switching every time would be exhausting for my users. Any ideas? Thanks.! I've tried customs segues as well, doesn't work.